# Is there a way to get space between char in ML kit android

Tags: android, kotlin, ocr, google-mlkit, text-recognition

I am developing a text scanner application by using ML kit. I am getting proper response. And text is coming with different blocks. Is there a way to know each block of text has space or not?

Comment: it's not clear exactly what do you mean by space, ml-kit text-recognizer if succeed in scanning will give you blocks of text(paragraphs) , each block has lines of text, each line has elements (words),  and each element has symbols, when you said 'space' in your question, do you mean the normal whitespace ?

Comment: ML-Kit text-recognizer is by definition a text-recognizer only! To go further in text analysis you need a text-interpreter.

Comment: @JamalN Blocks are not paragraph. ML kit might consider one word as two blocks. How can I conclude there is no space in between.

Comment: @SudoKoach Any sample you have noticed?

Comment: @DeepuGeorgeJacob Yeah you are right, I was just trying to make things looks simpler. It will be helpful to get answers if you can provide a picture for the text that you are dealing with.

Comment: No, I don't know of any "text interpreter"! The term "interpreter" was the first term that came to my mind for the post processing of the output raw data of a text-recognizer. The notions of blocks, lines and elements of a text recognizer have nothing to do with the syntaxic notions of paragraph, line, word, punctuation signs,.... You may have portions of two lines in the same block, two portions of a line in two different blocks, an element may contain a word with or without a space character or else with or without a punctuation sign!

Comment: @JamalN You can any text or number. sometime it will be in different blocks. try this work 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis'

Comment: Finally, I made it, but it's not just a generic one that only supports my needs. Thank you all for your support here.